# How to allot sections in a structure member by taking subject from user in as another Structure member in c language

Tags: c, structure

```
/*Take value and store in structure member, compare with constant
  do batch allotment in it.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    struct student{
        float mrk;
        char sub[10];
        char sec[10];
    } st[2];
    int i;
    float *p=&st[i].mrk;
    clrscr();
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter 12th mrks: ");
        scanf("%f", &st[i].mrk);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter subject: ");
        gets(st[i].sub);
    }
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if (st[i].sub=="cse")
            strcpy(st[i].sec,"A");   //st[i].sec="A";
        else if (st[i].sub=="me")
            strcpy(st[i].sec,"B");   //st[i].sec="B";
        else
            strcpy(st[i].sec,NULL);  //st[i].sec=NULL;
    }
    printf("\n numbers \t sub \tsec \n");
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\t%s\t%s\n",st[i].mrk,st[i].sub,st[i].sec);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Hello. This is the code. Please help. I'm unable to get the output for alloting sections according to the subject taken from user. It prints nothing over there and there is no error in turbo c7 compiler that I'm working on.

Comment: Always initialise your variables. It's the simplest, cheapest, fastest way to avoid many bugs.

Comment: `st[i].sub=="cse"` O.O @Breakpoint: "teaches code" -> are you sure?

Comment: float *p=&st[i].mrk; 'i' is uninitialized here, p doesn't know where to point at. @Phantom sorry, I meant profs coming to classroom with mugged up codes and writing it down on a blackboard